# Vertical gradient on matplotlib polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking to generate a linear gradient for a polycollection in matplotlib. I have the following code that gives me a single block color

```
v = []
for k in range(0, len(xs) - 1):
    x = [xs[k], xs[k+1], xs[k+1], xs[k]]
    y = [ys[k], ys[k+1], ys[k+1], ys[k]]
    z = [zs[k], zs[k+1],       h,     h]
    v.append(zip(x, y, z))    
poly3dCollection = Poly3DCollection(v, facecolor='yellow', edgecolors='none')
```

I have played around with colormaps and interpolation but I can't quite seem to get this to work in the way I want. Specifically I need a linear gradient based on a number of greyscale values I supply (so no default jet color scheme). The gradient can be set once i.e. top x% of each polygon black then various shades of gray for same x% rather than this needing to be dynamically calculated for each polygon.

I did get the effect I wanted by saving to SVG and manually editing the image, but I need to do this all in code.

It strikes me this should be very straight forward so im not sure what I am missing